# typo3 templavoila template not available in Use Template Design drop down

Tags: templates, typo3

I create a new TemplaVoila template for my website. Now I'd like to add this templeate to the ROOT page under *Apereance* in the *Use Template Design* drop down. Unfortunately the template does not show up in the drop down. What do I have to do to get chance to select the template in the drop down?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in ROOT page properties you pointed the sysfolder with TemplaVoila'a structures and templates in field `General Record Storage Page` (`Resources` tab)